What are the correct or more common pronounciations when counting with 羽 (わ)?
I have seen different variants/pronounciations in different sources...
三羽 => さんわ or さんば ?
四羽 => よんわ or よんば or よわ ?
六羽 => ろくわ or ろっぱ ?
八羽 => はちわ or はっぱ ?
十羽 => じゅうわ or じゅっぱ or じっぱ ?
Which variants/pronounciations are correct, or at least more usual/common/conventional?

７羽 → ななわ？しちわ？ 　チャイコフスキーは「[四羽]{しわ}の白鳥」
